# I'm working on creating an animation of a periodontal (gums) procedure and was looking for the best method to go about animating the gums

Tags: animation

As the title suggests, I've been tasked with creating an animation which shows a procedure for addressing gum disease. I have a reference video to work off of, which is here:

[Example video, not graphic but not for the extremely squeamish.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vmsj00Jd4UQ&feature=youtu.be)

In particular I'm looking at what's happening around 45 seconds. The gum is pulled back and forth repeatedly by that instrument. So far I've been experimenting with a cloth simulation, pinning the top of the gum part of my model, but after experiments with tension and all of that, I'm starting to tell this might not be the best way to to do this.

I had initially thought of just using a combination of shape keys and lattices to more or less match the motion between the instrument and the gums, but this would certainly be more time. If that's the best way then great, but I wanted to see if there are any better paths. I'm no expert but not a novice, so you don't have to be super detailed. I just need to figure out the best route. I appreciate any help in advance!